# How we can call channel data parameter to Azure bot

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot

const styleSet = window.WebChat.createStyleSet({
bubbleBackground: '#99ccff',
bubbleFromUserBackground: '#33adff',
rootHeight: '100%',
rootWidth: '100%'
});
styleSet.textContent = {
...styleSet.textContent,
fontFamily: "'Arial','Helvetica',sans-serif",
fontWeight: 'bold'
};

```
   var channelObj = turnContext.Activity.ChannelData.ToString();
                var channelData = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(channelObj);
                var customdata = channelData["TenantId"].ToString();

                var d1 = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token })
                 window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
                         directLine: Object.assign({}, d1, {
                             postActivity: activity => {
                                 var newActivity = object.assign({}, activity, { channelData: {
                                     "TenantId": "@ViewBag.Tennatid"
                             }
                         });
                                 alert("TenantId");
                                 return d1.postActivity(newActivity);
                             }
                        }),
                        userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
                        username: 'Web Chat User',
                        locale: 'en-US',
                        // Passing 'styleSet' when rendering Web Chat
                        styleSet,

                    },
                document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Comment: What does this mean? Please provide proper explanation of your question.

Comment: I am not able to call { channelData: {  "TenantId": "@ViewBag.Tennatid" } to my Azure bot compoer where in API Request  Body parameter as {"TenantId" = "${turncontext.activity.channeldata}"}.

Comment: see whatever changes i do in azure bot composer we publish that and via token window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }) we get an output on web....Right ? 

Then in visual studio when i say { channelData: { "TenantId": "@ViewBag.Tennatid" }
then how it get publish or affect your Azure Bot Composer (In API Body parameter )

Comment: I'm afraid I still have no idea what you are trying to achieve, however it would probably be a good idea to have a look at the [Composer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/) and the [bot docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: from above code i want to get data to my Azure Bot composer i.e - "TenantId": "@ViewBag.Tennatid" through visual studio code.

Comment: Your bot should know its Tenant ID before running, assuming you published it. Composer only publishes MultiTenant bots from its publish utility, which do not need a Tenant ID set to function.